# Visual Studio 2010 doesn't find the [DllImport("")]

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dllimport

I'm trying to use an C++ library in my c# application but my Visual Studio 2010 doesn't know the [DllImport("")]-method at all. He always ask me to generate the Methodstub for DllImport.

I already added the "using System.Runtime.InteropServices;" but it doesn't work.

Thanks for your helpt!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using the DLLImport in the wrong spot in your code.  You didn't post your code, but make sure its not in a method.  Try putting it in your class:

```
public class MyClass
{

    [DllImport("")]
    //method 

    public Class()
    {
    }

    // Other methods
}
```